# qtip2 reposition on target change

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I'm using [qtip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) to add a qtip next to the selected radio button among a set of grouped radio buttons. I can display the qtip correctly when the page loads, but when the selected radio changes, I'd like the qtip to follow along and point at the newly checked radio button.
I have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KHxgQ/20/) highlighting the issue. How can I get the qtip to point to the newly checked radio button?

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip_new/packages/nightly/jquery.qtip.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="mycss2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        #demo-simple{
            margin:100px;
        }

        input[type="radio"]{
            margin:20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo-simple" class="box">
        <div id="primary">
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="blah" checked /> Radio1
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="blah" /> Radio2
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip_new/packages/nightly/jquery.qtip.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#primary input[type='radio']:checked").qtip({
                content: {
                    text: 'I am selected'
                },
                show: {
                    ready: true,
                    delay: 0
                },
                hide: false,
                position: {
                    my: 'right center',
                    at: 'left center',
                    target: $("#primary input[type='radio']:checked")
                },
            });


            $("#primary input[type='radio']").change(function(evt){
                console.log(evt);
                console.log('changed');
                // manually reposition qtip??
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you can use this code [**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KHxgQ/21/)

following is the function you need to make

```
function updateqtip(){
 $("#primary input[type='radio']").qtip('destroy');
 $("#primary input[type='radio']:checked").qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'I am selected'
    },
    show: {
        ready: true,
        delay: 0
    },
    hide: false,
    position: {
        my: 'right center',
        at: 'left center',
        target: $("#primary input[type='radio']:checked")
    },
}); 
}
```

here is how you can use this function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   updateqtip();


   $("#primary input[type='radio']").change(function(evt){
     console.log(evt);
     console.log('changed');
     updateqtip();
    // manually reposition qtip??
  });
});
```